# Receiving request from Woopingbot/1.1

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, user-agent

so my question is the next one because I haven't been able to find any good info about this woopingbot.

Recenlty I have been receiving some Http request to my website, I can see in the apache log that the user agent is woopingbog/1.1, 
is this bot a good one or is some bot trying to find some security issues in my website?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am seeing this in my apache logs also.

Comment: I haven't , I check the ip address with who.is and is telling me that is some company in california, I really don't have any idea of what woopingboot is , if you find any please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bot is woorank.com up-time bot. It will check to see if your website is up to calculate uptime statistics.

There is another bot called woobot that will also check your site for SEO.